# modify the NDK and generate new experimental release packages

Tags: android, android-ndk, self-modifying

I am trying to modify the NDK and generate new experimental release packages with the doc 'android-ndk-r6\docs\DEVELOPMENT.html',but getting the following error after execute script $NDK/build/tools/rebuild-all-prebuilt.sh --toolchain-pkg=:

ERROR: Source directory doesn't support these ARCHs: arm
.
.
.
ERROR: Invalid sysroot: /tmp/ndk-Administrator/build/platforms/android-9/arch-arm

Use --sysroot= to indicate a valid one.

so please guide me how to resolve that